# long running windows service consuming memory

Tags: java, windows, memory, heap-memory

I have a Java process running as a service on Windows 7 [8 GB RAM] for 4-5 days without much activity on JVM. I notice that memory (private working set) [Task manager] is increasing day by day. It started with 45000K and now it has reached 115000K.

If I capture the heap dump of the Java process, the heap dump size is just 950KB. What is causing more memory consumption? or How should I proceed to find the root cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default maximum heap size of a 8 GB ( 8,000,000K ) machine, is 2 GB.  The Java process will use more memory if it decides this would improve throughput up to this limit.

Note: the size of the process includes ~ 150 MB of shared libraries so if you are including that it should be no surprise it is using 115 MB.

The real question is; do you really know this is a problem, it doesn't sound like much memory.

Comment: I have the process running for 1 month without using any functionality and the private working set has grown to 300 MB. I have some legacy native code written in C/C++ language which wraps Java application inside it. Once the memory reached 300MB, I again captured Java heap dump and found the total heap size is only 15 MB. I suspect leak is present in the native code.

Comment: @Vishik You need to look at live objects (after a full GC) but as you say it doesn't appear to be on the heap.  It could be a problem with the interaction between Java and C.  The C/C++ may expect you call close/clear/free on a resource which you are not doing. i.e. this is not strictly a bug in C/C++, but it is native resources which are consumed.

Comment: Yes this was the issue. We had some objects (BSTR pointers) in the native code which were not getting released from the memory. Used SysFreeString to release the memory.

Answer (score 0):

There are very big possibility that this is memory leak.
Basically some objects which should removed by GC are still have links on them.

You should use visualvm java tool to investigate this.
http://rejeev.blogspot.com/2009/04/analyzing-memory-leak-in-java.html

Comment: Yes it was a leak however the leak was present in the CPP code and not in Java.